# How can I extract/mount a .dd-ptcl-img file on a Mac?

Tags: mac, clonezilla

It is a clone --disk-- [EDIT]: (PARTITION NOT DISK) image from Clonezilla..
I do not have much experience with Macs so please explain like I'm 15..
I cannot find any guides on the internet..

Comment: Clonezilla doesn't look like a cross-platform tool. You might be at a dead-end. What were you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: "Clonezilla doesn't look like a cross-platform tool." Well how are you supposed to extract that file in the first place? I cannot find any guides.. I could only find the program called Osfmount (Only Windows) but that doesnt work out because the filesystem is APFS (Apple)..

Comment: The image will need to be in a format that a Mac-compatible program will be able to read. You need to work your problem backwards to figure out the path you need to take. Giving us more information about the constraints of your situation will help us better help you.

Comment: It depends on the way you created that image.
Which options did you use?

Comment: @davidbaumann I simply used Clonezilla to clone a partition on my Mac, chose "dd (supports all filesystems, but inefficient)" ... I found this seemingly useful guide and I will be attempting the steps mentioned..: [link](https://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/43_read_ntfsimg_content.faq#43_read_ntfsimg_content.faq)

Comment: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVOihefKE7w) Also very useful

Comment: So the initial post was about a disk image, now you say it was a partition image. Please edit in the initial post and declare image type (dd) and partition or disk.